# When somebody pushes a chair over, how do you instruct him to put it up back so it stands?

Tags: phrase-requests

My child sometimes pushes a chair over so that the chair lies flat on the floor. I'd like to instruct the child to make the chair stand again.

Pull up a chair seems to be more close to the meaning of "sit with us".
So maybe "Put the chair up?" or "Stand the chair?"
How would a native English speaker instruct his child to bring the chair back up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the word "put" you could say "put the chair upright" or "...right side up." As others have said "pick the chair up" is the more common way to say it.

Comment: I would say, and have said, "pick that chair up!".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Totally right. For some reason I couldn't think of that when I first answered.